# Custom Icon Set Problem with React-native-vector-icons + Icomoon

Tags: reactjs, fonts, react-native, react-native-vector-icons

I want to use my custom icons with react-native-vector-icons and Icomoon. I generated .tff and selection.js with Icomoon and put them into my project with react-native-link but The icons that I tried to use seen as empty square.

I will share with you my code and screenshoot.

Here is my import code

```
import { createIconSetFromIcoMoon } from 'react-native-vector-icons';
import selectionConfig from "../selection.json"
const Icon = createIconSetFromIcoMoon(selectionConfig,"icomoon","icomon.ttf");
<Icon name="bag" size={64} />
```

This is my package.json edit:

```
 "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
        "resources/fonts"
    ]
},
```

And this is the screenshot of icon:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgcdB.png)

Note: I put my font files under "./resources/fonts" and put selection.json under my "src" folder and I used "react-native link react-native-vector-icons" code for link these"

How Can I solve this issue?

Comment: Did you solve this? Im struggling with the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

I think maybe you have forgetten to run react native link, if you did and still does not show the icon, try delete the build file and retry.

There are two way to get your custom icon working, if linking does not help you, you may try the manual way.

This answer is referenced here: https://medium.com/bam-tech/add-custom-icons-to-your-react-native-application-f039c244386c

### a) React Native link

1. Put your .ttf in a ./resources/fonts folder at the base of your project
2. Add this piece of code at the first level of your package.json :

   "rnpm": { "assets": [ "resources/fonts" ] },
3. In your terminal: react-native link

### b) Manual

Android: Copy your .ttf inside the `./android/app/src/main/assets/fonts` folder of your RN project.

### If it still does not show

delete android `build` folder and rerun

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues and it's because the `rnpm` in the package is [depreciated](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/2945), I solved it by creating **`react-native.config.js`** file and then I did run the link command:

Here is `react-native.config.js` file.

```
module.exports = {
  project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {},
  },
  assets: ['./resources/fonts'],
};
```

After creating a file and adding the above code snippet, run the following command:

**`react-native link`**

Answer (score -1):

If you prefer to use icons as SVG, there is an easier way to do this. I hope [react-icomoon](https://github.com/aykutkardas/react-icomoon#react-native---demo) will be of use to you.

Create Icon component

```js
import IcoMoon from "react-icomoon";
import { Svg, Path } from "react-native-svg";
const iconSet = require("./selection.json");

const Icon = (props) => (
  <IcoMoon
    native
    SvgComponent={Svg}
    PathComponent={Path}
    iconSet={iconSet}
    {...props}
  />
);

export default Icon;
```

Then use

```js
import Icon from "./Icon";

<Icon icon="pencil" size={20} color="orange" />
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).